# Методы класса в разных QThread потоках

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Допустим, есть такой класс:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA();
    B();
    C();
private:
    int d, e, f;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы B() и C() запускались в разных потоках. Не хочу создавать класс Worker или класс WorkerThread, наследуемый от Qthread т.к. нужно внутри B() и C() использовать приватные переменные класса ClassA. Как лучше всего запустить B() и C() в разных потоках?

Comment: This is StackOverflow in Russian for questions in Russian language. Please either translate your question into Russian or ask the same question on [StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Embedder, видел подобный вопрос и там автор ответил в комментах, мол ему рассказали что на стеке нужно исключительно на английском общаться :)

Comment: Не знал, что русская версия отдельная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой путь это [QtConcurrent::run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html):

```
ClassA object;
QtConcurrent::run(object, &ClassA::B);
QtConcurrent::run(object, &ClassA::C);
```

Comment: Понял как сделать это с использованием WorkerThread ибо у QtConcurrent есть свои минусы. Нужно в WorkerThread объявить публичную переменную std::function<void()> work;, в run() выполнить просто work(), а перед workerThread->start() сделать workerThread->work = std::bind(&ClassA::B, this);